# Call a Vue.js function inside app.blade.php on button click

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Hy Guys,

I need to call a Vue.js function inside `app.blade.php` file. It should be triggered on a button click.

Here is the code sample I've used.

```
<button onclick="changeItem()">Saved Items</button>
```

`changeItem()` is a Vue.js function.

Kindly help :)

Comment: You might want to read the relevant [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.blade` define the component

```
<div id="app">
   <example-component></example-component>
</div>
```

By defualt laravel will include Vue JS packages in `resources\js\app.js`

In your `resources\js\components\ExampleComponent.vue` (Below Code)

```
<template>

    <button  v-on:click="say">Say what</button>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

  // define methods under the `methods` object
  methods: {
    say: function (event) {
      // `this` inside methods points to the Vue instance
      alert('Hello ')
      // `event` is the native DOM event
      if (event) {
        alert(event.target.tagName + " Clicked ")
      }
    }
  }
    }
</script>
```

**Run** : `npm run watch` `// To compile app.js`

**Please** `mark/upvote` if this finds helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="app">
  <button @click="changeItem">
    {{message}}
  </button>
</div>

new Vue({
  data: {
    message: "Save Items"
  },
  methods: {
    changeItem() {
        alert("Clicked!")
    }
  }
})
```

@click="changeItem" it is short form v-on:click="changeItem"

[Please read this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html)